# The App is working fine in emulator but not in phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-wifi, wifimanager

So my aim main is to make an app that can send messages from one phone to another without any internet connectivity. So as a first step I tried to create an app to switch wifi On/Off and show the available wifi devices. The app seems to work fine on emulator but does not work on the phone. Even the basic toggling of wifi didn't work on the phone. I've attached my MainActivity.java file. Kindly help.

MainActivity.java:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WifiManager wifiManager;
    TextView wifiStatusTextView;
    TextView wifiListView;
    Switch wifiSwitch;
    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Defining Variables
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiStatusTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_status_text_view);
        wifiListView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wifi_list);
        wifiSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.wifi_switch);
        registerReceiver(mWifiScanReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        wifiManager.startScan();

        /* Checking wifi state.
         * If wifi is enabled, display "wifi is on" and set toggle button to on position.
         * If Wifi is disabled, display "wifi is off" and set toggle button to off position.
         */
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi is currently ON");
            wifiSwitch.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi is currently OFF");
            wifiSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }

        /* adds listener to toggle button
         * If toggle is checked, wifi is enabled and "Wifi is on" is displayed.
         * If toggle is unchecked, wifi is enabled and "Wifi is off" is displayed.
         */
        wifiSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                    wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi is currently ON");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wifi may take a moment to turn on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    wifiStatusTextView.setText("Wifi is currently OFF");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, 87);
            }
        }
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mWifiScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)) {
                List<ScanResult> mScanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();

                for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                    sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                    sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).SSID);
                    sb.append("\n");
                }
                wifiListView.setText(sb);
            }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Did you check that in "logcat"?

Comment: yes I checked logcat it's fine